# Wordpress one custom post permalink structure inside other custom post permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

It's a Membership website.

Listing (`Custom Post Type - 1`)

Team Member (`Custom Post Type - 2`)

When showing a single post for a listing

Then showing below all Team members for this listing.

But when I click a Team Member for a single post.

Then show WordPress Normal Permalink like this

```
http://exampol.com/team-member ( custom post type -2 ) / single post link/
```

Normal WordPress permalink for listing.

```
http://exampol.com/ listing ( custom post type -1 ) / single post link/
```

I want to show this type(Below) of permalink. Can it possible?

```
http://exampol.com/ listing ( custom post type -1 ) / single-post-link//team-member ( custom post type -2 ) / single-team-member-link/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've conducted some research and found out this cool topic which I believe it will help you.
https://1fix.io/blog/2016/02/05/parent-from-another-cpt/

Basically, and I'm quoting from the article, you need to create the CPTs:

```
    <?php
// Register Custom Post Types
function my_register_cpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Courses', 'Post Type General Name', '1fix' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Course', 'Post Type Singular Name', '1fix' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Courses', '1fix' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Courses', '1fix' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Course', '1fix' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'course', $args );
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Lessons', 'Post Type General Name', '1fix' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Lesson', 'Post Type Singular Name', '1fix' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Lessons', '1fix' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Lessons', '1fix' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Lesson', '1fix' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'lesson', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_cpt' );
```

And then you need to add meta box to relate the parent post type to the child post type:

```
<?php
function my_add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'lesson-parent', 'Course', 'lesson_attributes_meta_box', 'lesson', 'side', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_boxes' );

function lesson_attributes_meta_box( $post ) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
    $pages = wp_dropdown_pages( array( 'post_type' => 'course', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __( '(no parent)' ), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0 ) );
    if ( ! empty( $pages ) ) {
        echo $pages;
    }
}
```

After that you need to set the permalink structure:

```
<?php
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%lesson%', '([^/]+)', 'lesson=');
    add_permastruct('lesson', '/lesson/%course%/%lesson%', false);
    add_rewrite_rule('^lesson/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?','index.php?lesson=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

And finally, update the permalink of the post:

```
<?php
function my_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'lesson' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        return $permalink;

    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent_post = get_post( $parent );

    $permalink = str_replace('%course%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

Comment: This code is working but when I add this code than normal page permalink not working it's showing 404 pages. can you help me?